# Union of powers of a well-ordered set is well-ordered.

Tags: well-orders, ordered-groups

While studing a certain type of rings I was trying to solve the following exercise (which is what I need to prove that this ring is well defined):

**Let $S$ be a well-ordered subset of an ordered group $(G,<)$ such that $g>1~\forall g\in S$. Prove that $\bigcup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}S^n$ is well-ordered and that $\forall~g\in G$ the set $\lbrace n\in\mathbb{N}\mid g\in S^n\rbrace$ is finite.**

Where well-ordered means that every non-empty subset has a unique minimum.

To prove that  $\bigcup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}S^n$ is well-ordered i tried the following:

Let $A\subset \bigcup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}S^n$, then $A=A\cap \bigcup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}S^n=\bigcup\limits _{n\in\mathbb{N}}(A\cap S^n)$. Let $I\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the set of indices such that $A\cap S^n\neq\emptyset$. Then $\forall~n\in I$ we have that $A\cap S^n$ is a non-empty subset of $S^n$, thus since $S^n$ is well-ordered there exists $a_n=\min\limits_{g\in A\cap S^n}\lbrace g\rbrace$. From this, one have constructed a set $\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n\in I}$ which is bounded below by $1$. Hence, this set has a minimum $a=\min \lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n\in I}$, which is the minimum of $A$. Is this right?

For the second part I don't have any idea, I guess that we have to argue by contradiction and prove that if the set is infinite then there must be some $S^n$ such that it is not well-ordered, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could there be an additional hypothesis? Because $G=\mathbb{Z}$ is ordered and $S=\{-1\}$ is well-ordered, but $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S^n = \mathbb{Z}_-$ is not.

Comment: @FlorianR yes sorry, I have corrected it

Comment: To show $\bigcup_n S^n$ is well-ordered, you have to show *every non-empty subset* has a least element. Showing the entire set has a least element is not sufficient. I sugest starting by proving for each $n, S^n$ is well ordered.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I allredy knew that $S^n$ is well-ordered. I corrected the proof, can you check it?

Comment: You only know that $S$ is well-ordered. You have not yet shown that $S^n$ is well-ordered, though you used that in your proof. Why should the set $\{a_n\}_{n\in I}$ have a minimum element? $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ are both ordered groups under addition, and for neither one do bounded countable sets have to have a minimum (for $\Bbb R$ they have to have an infimum, but it need not be in the set). As a hint, note that there is another set than $S$ used in this construction that you know from the start is well-ordered.

Comment: For the second part, as you have it currently stated, it is false. If $1 \in S$, then $1 \in S^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I should have said it, but in a previous exercise I already proven that the product of two well-ordered sets is well ordered, thus I can use that $S^n$ is well ordered. For the second part, you were right, $1\notin S$ otherwise the exercise is false, so we must assume that all elements of $S$ are $>1$.

Comment: Okay. You still need to explain why $\{a_n\}$ has to have a minimum element.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't know how to do it, can u give me any hint? :)

Comment: For the first statement, let $\bar S = S \cup \{1\}$. Then $\bar S$ is also well-ordered and $\bar S^n \subset \bar S^{n+1}$ for all $n$. Since you've already proved $\bar S^n$ must be well-ordered for all $n$, this gives you that any finite union of the $bar S^n$ is well-ordered. Now figure out how to prove the full union is. For the second statement, if $g \in S^n$, it is the product of $n$ elements of $S$. Some of those elements $s$ will have $s^k \ge g$ for some $k$. Others may have $s^k < g$ for all $k$. Multiplying together the latter a $g'$ to which the same can be done. This has to end

Comment: @PaulSinclair What you did for the second statement does not have any sense, since for every $s>1, g\in G$ there is some integer $k$ such that $s^k>g$. Am I right?

Comment: No. The Archimedean principle does not hold in general. For example, $\Bbb Z^2$ under addition and lexigraphically ordered: $(x, y) < (a,b) \iff (x < a) \vee (x = a \wedge y < b)$ ($G$ is not required to be well-ordered, only $S$). In this group "$1$" is $(0,0)$, and setting $s= (0,1)$, we have $s > (0,0)$. But for any $k, s^k = (0,k) < (1,0)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see, thanks but I am still stucked, It shoudn't be that hard but I don't know what I am missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an answer in the following articles :

1. *On Ordered Divisions Rings*, by B. H. Neumann, in the Transactions of the American Mathematical Society (vol. 66) at p.206 where it was originally stated and proved I think. I have a picture of the demonstration of it if you want. The authors uses quite elementary arguments that relie on the notion of Archimedean classes on a (semi)group.
2. *Foundations of analysis over surreal number field*, by N. L. Ailing (the PDF can be found not so difficultly on internet) at p.261. It is refered as Neumann's lemma. The demonstration is different but still uses elementary arguments that relies this time on convex subgroups.

I'll let you read it in the corresponding papers because both of these answers are really too long (but still elementary don't worry) to be re written here.